# Limit number of displayed items with th:each

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In the following thymeleaf code, I want limit the number of displayed items from list `produtos` to a specific number:

```
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4" th:each="item2 : ${produtos}" th:if="${item.getId() == item2.getCategoria().getId()}">
    <h2 th:text="${item2.getNome()}"></h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <a th:href="@{/produto/__${item2.getId()}__.htm}" class="thumbnail">
          <img th:src="@{/Produto/icone__${item2.getId()}__.jpeg}" width="64" height="64" th:alt="${item2.getNome()}"/>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p th:text="${#strings.substring(item2.getDescricao(), 0, 140)}"></p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" th:href="@{/produto/__${item2.getId()}__.htm}" role="button">Detalhes &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
```

but in the official documentation I can't be able to find anything saying how to do this. Anyone can give any hints about that?

**UPDATE**

I try to solve this issue adding this to my code:

```
th:if="${itemStat.index < NUM}"
```

the final code is this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4" th:each="item2 : ${produtos}" th:if="${item2Stat.index < NUM}" th:if="${item.getId() == item2.getCategoria().getId()}">
```

but I get this error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: the value of the attribute "th:if" associated to an element "null" shouldn't have the character '<'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve this issue adding this to my code:

```
th:each="item2 : ${#numbers.sequence(1,3)}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a second Parameter in your th:each attribute like in your example:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4" th:each="item2, stat : ${produtos}" th:if="${item.getId() == item2.getCategoria().getId()}">
```

then you have access of additional data in this attribute. A full explanantion is here:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration
under topic 6.2

Comment: this don't work for me because the loop `item2 : ${produtos}` is placed insde another; each loop iterate over a constant number of elements and select some of them, in different positions in the list. A solution which will fit here would be increasing a variable with 1 each iteration and when this variable reaches a specific number. break the loop.